# How to change the default font size of an article

Tags: fontsize

Maybe I misunderstood the command, but to me \documentclass[50pt]{article} doesn't work. The font size seems fixed no matter what I do the the option.
Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[500pt]{article}
\begin{document}
James\\
John\\
\end{document}
```

the result doesn't change no matter what size I use in the parameter. Maybe i misunderstood the meaning of the argument?

Comment: "...the result doesn't change no matter what size I use in the parameter." Actually, did you try `10pt`, `11pt`, or `12pt`? :-) In fact, these three parameter values are the *only* choices that the basic LaTeX document classes -- `article`, `report`, and `book` -- are trained to understand. The KOMA-Script document classes -- `scrartcl`, `scrreport`, and `scrbook` -- are supposed to be able to handle *arbitrary* default font sizes if the option is set via `fontsize=...` in the `\documentclass` instruction. However, even the KOMA-Script classes have a practical limit of `fontsize=136pt`.